# *ngFor not working and no error in console

Tags: angular

I went through most of the questions where "ngFor is not working". below are the details.

**app.modules.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';    
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';    
import { TweetComponent } from './tweet.component';    
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({    
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, TweetComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })

export class AppModule { }
```

**app.components.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>List of tweets</h1>
            <tweets><tweets>`,
 })

export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

**tweet.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core"
@Component({
   selector: 'tweets',
   template: `<ul>
                <li *ngFor="let item of myList">
                     <span> {{ item}}</span>
                  </li>  
              </ul> `
})

export class TweetComponent {
        myList: ['.net', 'C#', 'web services'];
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Elements:

[image: Elements]

And there are errors in console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should've been

```
myList = ['.net', 'C#', 'web services'];
```

if you use `:` it will try to declare the fields type.

Example:

```
myList: Array<string> = ['.net', 'C#', 'web services'];
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues,

values in the array myList should be assigned using **`=`**,

```
myList= ['.net', 'C#', 'web services'];
```

and you're missing  tag on template

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>List of tweets</h1>
            <tweets></tweets>`,
 })
```